What does "inside" refer to when we say that the electric field inside a conductor is 0?
According to my textbooks, electric field inside a conductor is always 0, even when there's a charged cavity inside of it. If we consider a gaussian surface as shown in the figure, isn't there a net electric field inside the conductor?
So my question is this: What exactly does "inside" refer to in the general case. Does it include the non conducting/air part inside a hollow conductor, or just the conductor part of the whole setup(just the metal ring).


Note that only the macroscopic field vanishes inside a conductor.

Inside the conductor means inside the conductor. What is not conducting is not a conductor.

"Inside the conductor" refers to the actual material of the conductor, usually metal, the "meat" of the conductor. The electric field within the cavity may be non zero, but inside the actual conductor all of the charges redistribute to produce a net zero electric field.

Probably a subject for another question, but if it's E=0 inside the conductor then what causes the force that moves the electrons along the wire?

@user4574 I think the answer is nothing. If we assume that E is exactly 0 inside the conductor, we can't also assume that electric current consists of the motion of electrons; those assumptions are incompatible.

@user4574 OP's question is tagged electrostatics (non-moving charges). The E=0 rule applies within that scope.

@user4574 Net electric field produced by the charges in the conductor on their own is zero, but applied external electric field is not zero, which moves the charges of conductor in one way.

E=0 is a limiting case for infinitely conductive conductors. If you want the electric field dynamics of current flow inside a conductor, you have to do a more complex analysis -- which is not required for a whole set of engineering problems where you can use E=0.

@david No, the limit of infinite conductivity is not required for the E=0 rule to be valid in electrostatics. In any material with measurable nonzero conductivity, E must vanish when charges are not moving.

The "inside" refers to the material of the conductor itself and does not include any cavities or gaps. The existence of cavities does not break the electrostatic rule of zero electric field inside conductors. In your example, the charge $q$ induces a surface charge totaling $-q$ on the wall of the cavity, so the Gaussian surface drawn encloses a total charge of zero. As a result, if the conductor is neutral as a whole, there will be a total charge of $q$ on its outer surface. This is explained in section 2.5 of Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics.

In electrostatic equilibrium, the electric field must be zero within the "bulk" of a conductor. This follows from the microscopic version of Ohm's Law
$$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}$$
where $\vec{J}$ is current density, $\sigma$ is conductivity, and $\vec{E}$ is the electric field.
Since by the assumption that we are in electrostatic equilibrium, there is no current. I.e. $\vec{J}=0$
And since we are considering a conductor, the conductivity $\sigma$ cannot be $0$. Thus $\vec{E}$ must be $0$.
